# C# Issue handling memory usage for SearchResultAttributeCollection LDAP

Tags: c#, memory-management

Using the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` library:

I have a class `LdapItemOperator` that takes a `SearchResultEntry` object from an LDAP query (not Active Directory related) and stores the attributes for the object in a field: `readonly SearchResultAttributeCollection LdapAttributes`.

The problem I am experiencing is that when I have a large operation the garbage collector seems to **never delete these objects** after they ought to have been disposed because of the `LdapAttributes` field in my objects, at least I think that's the problem. What ways can I try to dispose of the objects when they are no longer required? I can't seem to find a way to incorporate a `using` statement in there, although I only have little experience with it.

As an example, let's say I have the following logic:

```
List<LdapItemOperator> itemList = GetList(ldapFilter);
List<bool> resultList = new List<bool>();
foreach (IdmLdapItemOperator item in itemList) {
    bool result = doStuff(item);
    resultList.Add(result);
}
//Even though we are out of the loop now, the objects are still stored in memory, how come? Same goes for the previous objects in the loop, they seem to remain in memory
Logic.WriteResultToLog(result);
```

After a good while of running the logic on large filesets, this process starts taking up enormous amounts of memory, of course...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be a little confused about how GC works. You can never know exactly when GC will run. And objects you are still holding a reference to will not be collected (unless it's a weak reference...).

Also "disposing" is yet another different concept, that hasn't much to do with GC.

Basically, all objects will be in memory *already* after the call to `GetList`. And memory consumption will not change much after that, the foreach loop shouldn't affect it at all.

Without knowing your implementation, maybe try returning an enumerable instead of a single list, or make multiple batched calls.

Comment: That's the strange part about it, I have the list, and then everytime i loop over an item in the list it seems to make a duplicate item in memory of it or something and the memory just keeps going up and up and up without there being an obvious reason in it.
I do have some recursions in the objects themselves, but they are only called upon sometimes.

Comment: @ThomErnst Basically impossible to say more without seeing the rest of the code.